# Как отредактировать информацию в БД (RedBean)

Tags: php, mysql

Синтаксических ошибок нет, но на выходе получаем HTTP 500.
Что я делаю не так? Служит для редактирования уже существующей колонки

```
<?php

    require "db.php";

    $data = $_POST;

    if ( isset($data['do_change']) ) {

        $errors = array();

        if ( trim($data['email']) == '' ) {
            $errors[] = 'Введите почту!';
        }

        if ( $data['firstname'] == '' ) {
            $errors[] = 'Введите имя!';
        }

        if ( $data['lastname'] == '' ) {
            $errors[] = 'Введите фамилию!';
        }

        if ( $data['password'] == '' ) {
            $errors[] = 'Введите пароль!';
        }

        if ($data['login'] != $_SESSION['access']->login) {
            if ( R::count('users', "login = ?", array($data['login'])) > 0 ) {
                $errors[] = 'Пользователь с таким логином уже существует!';
            }
        }

        if ($data['email'] != $_SESSION['access']->email) {
            if ( R::count('users', "email = ?", array($data['email'])) > 0 ) {
                $errors[] = 'Пользователь с такой почтой уже существует!';
            }
        }

        if ( empty($errors) ) {

            $user = R::dispense('users');
            $user->email = $data['email'];
            $user->firstname = $data['firstname'];
            $user->lastname = $data['lastname'];
            $user->phone = $data['phone'];
            $user->password = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            R::store($user);
            header('Location: http://akciapdd.ru/instatop/profile.php?success_edit');

        } else {
            echo '<div class="register_error">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: $cat = R::load('category', 2);
$cat->title = "Новое значение"; 
R::store($cat);

Comment: Вам нужно сначала загрузить существующие данные например load или findOne а потом сохранить store